# How to get object value from another object

Tags: php, oop

It's been a while since I last work with object.  I can't figure out what I did wrong.  I have a class that contain another class as a property.  After instantiating ItemDetail() inside Item(), I can't get the value of description.  var_dump($item) give me NULL for the value of $detail.  Please help.  Thank you.

```
<?php
class Item
{
  private $name;
  private $detail;

  function __construct() {
    $this->name = 'some name';
    $this->detail = new ItemDetail();
  }

  function getDetail() {
    return $this->detail;
  }
}

class ItemDetail
{
  private $description;

  function __construct() {
    $this->description = 'some description';
  }

  function getDescription {
    return $this->description;
  }
}

$item = new Item();
echo $item->getDetail()->getDescription();
//var_dump($item);
?>
```

Comment: What are you trying to get, from an object, without any methods?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the scope of your class properties, or define a method that returns the values. Example:

```
class Item
{
  private $name;
  private $detail;

  function __construct() {
    $this->name = 'some name';
    $this->detail = new ItemDetail();
  }

    public function getDescription() {
        return $this->detail->getDescription();
    }
}

class ItemDetail
{
  private $description;

  function __construct() {
    $this->description = 'some description';
  }

    public function getDescription() { 
        return $this->description;
    }
}

$item = new Item();
echo $item->getDescription();
```

If you make your properties public, you can get them like this as well:

```
class Item
{
  public $name;
  public $detail;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->name = 'some name';
    $this->detail = new ItemDetail();
  }
}

class ItemDetail
{
  public $description;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->description = 'some description';
  }
}

$item = new Item();
echo $item->detail->description;
```

It's all about visibility

Comment: My code actually has the accessor methods, just like your first example.  In the Item class, I have a method getDetail() that returns $this->detail.  So in the main, I have $item->getDetail()->getDescription().  I get this error: Call to a member function getDescription() on a non-object ...

Comment: We'd need to see the full code to see what you're doing. You can't chain methods like that unless you're returning `$this` in the called methods.. but doing it this way would produce the wrong result anyways.

Comment: That's basically what I have so far.  I just didn't include the accessor methods to make the classes shorter.  I know my code will definitely work in Java.  I'm just wondering how it has to be done in PHP.  I make the class properties private so that they're not accessible from outside.  I then create accessor methods to access those properties.  How can I display the value of $description from the main()?

Comment: Really need to see the code to be able to help.

Comment: Or study the first example I sent. The `$item->getDescription()` results from `ItemDetail::getDescription` returning `ItemDetail::description` up to `Item::getDescription`... so there's 2 returns from just one call (if this makes sense).

Comment: I've updated the code.  That's what I have so far since it's not working.

Comment: `function getDescription {` is your problem. It should be `function getDescription() {` - missing parenthesis

Comment: Since `Item::$detail` is an object, you can chain methods to call `ItemDetail` methods/public properties. But this may result in an excess exposure of data.

Comment: It's function getDescription() {}.  I mistyped it.  That's what I thought.  Since Item::$detail is an instance of ItemDetail, it should be able to call the public methods of ItemDetail, but instead I get the Fatal Error: Call to a member function getDescription() on a non-object ... I tried it in Java and C#, and it worked fine.  I'm just wondering why it doesn't work in PHP.